Casimir elements of direct sum of Lie algebras
Let $\mathfrak{g}_1$ and $\mathfrak{g}_2$ be two finite Lie algebras that may have one or more Casimir elements of their universal enveloping algebras, $\mathcal{C}_1$ and $\mathcal{C}_2$. By definition of the Casimir elements $[\mathcal{C}_1,g_1]=0~\forall g_1 \in \mathfrak{g}_1$ and $[\mathcal{C}_2,g_2]=0~\forall g_2 \in \mathfrak{g}_2$. If we take the direct sum of $\mathfrak{g}_1$ and $\mathfrak{g}_2$, I believe we could consider this a new Lie algebra $\mathfrak{h}$ of dimensionality $\dim\mathfrak{g}_1+\dim\mathfrak{g}_2$ where the structure constants are given by
$$
[h_i,h_j]=\begin{cases}
f(\mathfrak{g}_1)^k_{ij}h_k, & \text{if}~i\le\dim\mathfrak{g}_1~\text{and}~j\le\dim\mathfrak{g}_1, \\
f(\mathfrak{g}_2)^k_{ij}h_k, & \text{if}~i>\dim\mathfrak{g}_1~\text{and}~j>\dim\mathfrak{g}_1, \\
0, & \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$
Now it is obvious that $[\mathcal{C}_1,h_i]=0$ and $[\mathcal{C}_2,h_i]=0$ (if we define the $\mathcal{C}_i$ in terms of the corresponding elements of $\mathfrak{h}$), and I believe $\mathcal{C}_1$ and $\mathcal{C}_2$ should span the center of the universal enveloping algebra of $\mathfrak{h}$. However if I calculated the Killing form of $\mathfrak{h}$ and used that to construct the quadratic Casimir element it would give me $\mathcal{C}_1+\mathcal{C}_2$ (assuming they are both also quadratic). By hand I could then find other elements that span the center of the universal enveloping algebra (e.g. $\mathcal{C}_1-\mathcal{C}_2$) - but is there a more rigorous way to find the second Casimir element of $\mathfrak{h}$? I have previously only ever come across examples where there is one Casimir element of a given order: does that imply that the second Casimir element here would be (a properly symmetrized version of) $\mathcal{C}_1\mathcal{C}_2$?

Casimir elements are, arguably, any elements of the centre of the universal enveloping algebra. It is common to choose a set of generators and to do so in a way that gives you nice homogeneous elements (that you always can do this is deducible from the PBW theorem I believe) but this is a choice. Thus either $\mathcal{C}_1, \mathcal{C}_2$ or $\mathcal{C}_1+\mathcal{C}_2, \mathcal{C}_1-\mathcal{C}_2$ are perfectly valid choices of Casimir elements. I'd probably go for the former as they will be a little easier to work with.
To be extra precise the universal enveloping algebra of $\mathfrak{g}_1 \oplus \mathfrak{g}_2$ can be identified as:
$$ \mathcal{U}(\mathfrak{g}_1 \oplus \mathfrak{g}_2) \cong \mathcal{U}(\mathfrak{g}_1) \otimes \mathcal{U}(\mathfrak{g}_2)$$
Then the easiest way to choose Casimir elements is as each $\mathcal{C}_1\otimes1$ for $\mathcal{C}_1$ a Casimir element for $\mathfrak{g}_1$ and each $1\otimes \mathcal{C}_2$ for $\mathcal{C}_2$ a Casimir element of $\mathfrak{g}_2$. Note that $\mathcal{C}_1+\mathcal{C}_2$ is really $\mathcal{C}_1\otimes1 + 1\otimes \mathcal{C}_2$ in this identification.
